# assembly function flow

Tags: function, assembly, x86, att, control-flow

I am reading a "programming from the ground up", if you don't know what this book is, you still can help me.

In this book(chapter 4) there are 2 things that I don't understand:

1. what `movl %ebx, -4(%ebp) #store current result` for.
2. and what does "current result" means

in marked section in the code below, there is:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
```

which means save `8(%ebp)` to `%ebx`, but the reason why I don't understand is, if the programmer want `8(%ebp)` to save to `-4(%ebp)`, why should `8(%ebp)` be passed through `%ebx`? Is "`movl 8(%ebp), -4(%ebp)`" akward? Or is there any typo in `movl 8(%ebp), %ebx #put first argument in %eax`?
(I think `%ebx` should be `%eax` or vice versa)

```
#PURPOSE: Program to illustrate how functions work
# This program will compute the value of
# 2^3 + 5^2
#Everything in the main program is stored in registers,
#so the data section doesn’t have anything.

.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start

_start:

pushl $3 #push second argument
pushl $2 #push first argument
call power #call the function
addl $8, %esp #move the stack pointer back
pushl %eax #save the first answer before

#calling the next function

pushl $2 #push second argument
pushl $5 #push first argument

call power #call the function
addl $8, %esp #move the stack pointer back
popl %ebx #The second answer is already

#in %eax. We saved the
#first answer onto the stack,
#so now we can just pop it
#out into %ebx

addl %eax, %ebx #add them together
#the result is in %ebx

movl $1, %eax #exit (%ebx is returned)
int $0x80

#PURPOSE: This function is used to compute
# the value of a number raised to
# a power.

#INPUT: First argument - the base number
# Second argument - the power to
# raise it to
#
#OUTPUT: Will give the result as a return value
#
#NOTES: The power must be 1 or greater
#
#VARIABLES:
# %ebx - holds the base number
# %ecx - holds the power
#
# -4(%ebp) - holds the current result
#
# %eax is used for temporary storage
#

.type power, @function
power:
pushl %ebp #save old base pointer
movl %esp, %ebp #make stack pointer the base pointer
subl $4, %esp #get room for our local storage
##########################################

movl 8(%ebp), %ebx #put first argument in %eax
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx #put second argument in %ecx
movl %ebx, -4(%ebp) #store current result

##########################################

power_loop_start:
cmpl $1, %ecx #if the power is 1, we are done
je end_power
movl -4(%ebp), %eax #move the current result into %eax
imull %ebx, %eax #multiply the current result by

#the base number
movl %eax, -4(%ebp) #store the current result
decl %ecx #decrease the power
jmp power_loop_start #run for the next power

end_power:
movl -4(%ebp), %eax #return value goes in %eax
movl %ebp, %esp #restore the stack pointer
popl %ebp #restore the base pointer
ret
```

Comment: I've found http://ref.x86asm.net/ to be a great instruction reference for x86/x86-64.  You'll see that there is no form of a mov instruction that will move between two memory operands (as Greg and Stephen have both answered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this:

```
 movl 8(%ebp), %ebx #put first argument in %eax
```

was a typo, and it should really be:

```
 movl 8(%ebp), %ebx #put first argument in %ebx
```

and if you noticed, later the code is correct:

```
 movl %ebx, -4(%ebp) #store current result
```

In the end, the author could have used `%eax` for this operation as well (instead of `%ebx`), there's no reason why he shouldn't since it wouldn't change the program at all.

But the comment could be a lot clearer and I believe that this is a typo as well. At this point, it would be better if it said: `#storing 1st argument on the local stack frame`.

**label power_loop_start** uses that variable and temporarily stores it in `%eax` for quick operations and then place it back on the same location on the stack for the next loop:

```
 movl %eax, -4(%ebp)   #store the current result
 decl %ecx             #decrease the power
 jmp  power_loop_start #run for the next power
```

Answer (score 2):

Many assembly opcodes accept only *one* memory operand (either source, or destination). This probably explains why a move from memory to memory is done through %ebx.

Answer (score 1):

As **Greg** hinted, x86, like most mainstream architectures, does not have an instruction that copies data from memory to memory[1].  Thus, you must copy data using a separate *load* and *store*.  First you load the data from the source memory into a register, then you store the data from that register to the destination memory.  That's all that is happening here.

[1] I know, I know, but let's leave `rep movs` out of this and keep things simple.

Comment: just to add to note 1, it is possible to push abc; pop def; too